# Is there a AOT for ReactJs like the Angular 4.0 has?

Tags: angular, reactjs

There is a [Ahead-Of-Time](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) compiler for Angular 4.0. Is there something similar for ReactJS, or there is no compiler needed for ReactJS?

Comment: i think web-pack dev server has this included, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

React is already doing that with JSX. This is one of the reasons why React people love to say , “It’s just JavaScript!”.

React doesn’t do AoT as that is primarily used to compile string templates to executable JavaScript so the browser doesn’t have to do that part.

React doesn't have two ways of compiling unlike angular (JIT and AOT).